# Selecting Items in dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Using Python 3

I have a dataframe sort of like this:

```
productCode   productType   storeCode   salesAmount  moreInfo
    111            1            111          111       info
    111            1            112          112       info
    456            4            456          456       info
```

and so on for thousands of rows

I want to select (and have a list with the codes for) the X amount of the best selling unique products for each different store.

How would I accomplish that?

Comment: what did you try to do? please share your code. Moreover, what is the productType means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'productCode': [111,111,456,123,125],
                   'productType' : [1,1,4,3,3],
                   'storeCode' : [111,112,112,456,456],
                   'salesAmount' : [111,112,34,456,1235]})


   productCode  productType  storeCode  salesAmount
0          111            1        111          111
1          111            1        112          112
2          456            4        112           34
3          123            3        456          456
4          125            3        456         1235
```

It sounds like you want the best selling product at each `storeCode`? In which case:

```
df.sort_values('salesAmount', ascending=False).groupby('storeCode').head(1)

   productCode  productType  storeCode  salesAmount
4          125            3        456         1235
1          111            1        112          112
0          111            1        111          111
```

Instead, if you want the best selling of each `productType` at each `storeCode`, then:

```
df.sort_values('salesAmount', ascending=False).groupby(['storeCode', 'productType']).head(1)

   productCode  productType  storeCode  salesAmount
4          125            3        456         1235
1          111            1        112          112
0          111            1        111          111
2          456            4        112           34
```

Comment: thanks for the help

just to clarify, I wanted the top 3 best selling products at each store, like the first answer

Comment: `.head(1)` is controlling how many are being returned. if you want top 3 then you can just change that to `.head(3)`